# Prepopulating my ASP.NET Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, ascx

I have this code in my .ascx file (the ascx file is used in my search.aspx and search.aspx.cs files):

```
        <form name="search" method="get" action="searchresults.aspx" id="searchform" runat="server">

            <p>Need to refine your search? Use the fields below to narrow results.</p><br />
            <input type="text" id="keywordSearch" value="Keyword" />
            <div class="advanceSearchBox">
                <p><b>Narrow results by:</b></p>

                <asp:Literal ID="ltrlExplorePopulation" runat="server" />

                <asp:Literal ID="ltrlExploreDatasource" runat="server" />

            </div>
            <img src="images/go_up.png" alt="GO" name="keywordSearchGO" width="34" height="24" id="keywordSearchGO" />
        </form>
```

I have data in my query string in my search.aspx.cs page that I want to put into the input of the form above. And the first literal ltrlExplorePopulation gets translated to this:

```
    <div class="narrowRes">Poulation</div><select class="narrowResSelect" name="population"><option value="0">All populations</option><option vale="1">Small population</option></select>
```

So how do I get my query string data into this form?

My search.aspx.cs Page_Load has this:

```
 string keywords = Request.QueryString["keywords"];
    string datasources = Request.QueryString["datasources"];
    string population = Request.QueryString["population"];
```

And I want to have keywords be set into the input above, population be set to the select statement, etc.  I'm not sure if using Form.Controls.? is correct?

Comment: Can you show us this query string in your search.aspx.cs page? Having some trouble figuring out what you're doing...

Answer (score 0):

Are the value in the options e.g. "All populations" and "Small Population" dynamic or static?

With static you can do like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="All Population" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Small Population" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And in code-behind set the value e.g.
DropDownList1.SelectedValue=population; //this comes from your querystring.

Please clarify if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Then declare just the dropdown without items and DataBind your options to it on first-time page load.